# when i try to fetch data between two selected date and if any selected date does not have data than it is not working.How to solve it?

Tags: android, sqlite

when i try to fetch data between two selected date and if any selected date does not have data than it is not working.How to solve it?

```
query = "SELECT * FROM expense_tb where date BETWEEN '" + toDate + "'AND '" + fromDate + "'";
    Cursor c1 = db.selectQuery(query);
    if (c1.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            money = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("money"));
            cat = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("selCat"));
            date = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("date"));
           } while (c1.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your query is vulnerable to injection.
2. You pass dates as literals and use `BETWEEN` clause.
3. You don't have any error handling.

Answer (score 0):

put it inside try catch. on exception show some toast or something.

Comment: I got my mistake.